# Trying to install SVN client Scientific Linux

Tags: linux, svn, yum, scientific-linux

I am trying to install SVN client on Scientific Linux but I am getting the following output if I do a "sudo yum install subversion"

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.7.8-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.3.so()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libneon.so.25()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-db43.x86_64 0:4.3.29-15.el6 will be installed
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package compat-openldap.x86_64 1:2.3.43-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6_2.2 will be installed
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.7.8-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libneon.so.25()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.7.8-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
httpd-tools-2.2.15-15.sl6.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with httpd-tools-2.2.15-15.sl6.x86_64
```

Comment: it looks like some broken rpm ... I had something like that when I disconnect from ssh while yum update was working ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installed packages (specifically `httpd-tools`) are out of sync with the distribution repositories. You need to get back into sync before you can move forward.

To resolve the issue:

1. Use `yum clean all` to erase your local cache and metadata. It will get rebuilt the next time you run `yum`.
2. Use `yum distro-sync` to bring your system into sync with the state of the repositories. This may both upgrade and downgrade packages, so inspect carefully what it intends to do before committing.

Once done, you should then be able to install further packages (such as `subversion`).

Answer (score 2):

from http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/

create `/etc/yum.repos.d/wandisco-svn.repo`

```
For CentOS/RHEL 6 Users:

[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

For CentOS/RHEL 5 Users:

[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/5/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

then
# yum clean all
# yum install subversion
# svn --version


run `# yum remove subversion` to remove old version
```

Comment: This worked for me on Scientific Linux 6.7